# Unable to install/download SDK from Android SDK manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools, google-play-services

I'm trying to install and use the library from Google Play Services, as I am following the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

However, I am getting this weird error where it says file not found and access is denied.

[image]

I've tried even updating or downloading new SDKs and it seems like I'm having this problem as well. So I'm wondering if I'm missing some steps that prevent me from downloading the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Ah how stupid of me.

This wasn't caused by any firewall settings/ anti-virus.

As the folder was placed in the Program Files, please do ensure that your Windows User Account has Full Control access rights.

This can be set in the properties of the folder under Security!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if there is either a download problem (firewall, antivirus), that blocks downloading or something like an automatic antivirus block for opening zip files?

Is Java allowed to use internet connection? Did you change something at the firewall settings there? Could you try do add the SDK Manager to the firewall allowed list?

Comment: the SDK manager used to work like a month ago, I didn't touch anything since then and now it suddenly doesn't work. I'll try to look at the firewall to see how it goes (though I highly doubt it's blocking it)

Comment: Sadly it doesn't... I completely switched off the Windows Firewall and it still doesn't install. Don't have any anti-virus currently